# Use datepicker inside <td> </td>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I can use datepicker in input tag

```
  <script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<input id="datepicker">
```

how can I use datepicker like this

```
<td id="datepicker"> </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the input field inside the `td` and use it to create the datepicker

```
<td id="datepicker"></td>
```

then

```
 $(function() {
    $('<input />').appendTo('#datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: I know it, but I just want use <td id="datepicker"> </td> because I have too many <td> tags to replace it with <input> tag. Is there another way?

Comment: @user3054044 you can insert a input tag using script and then initialize datepicker on them

Comment: also make sure that ID of an element is unique.... there should be only one element with a given ID

Comment: it works well but it break format css of my td.( white input appear inside green td )

Comment: why don't you apply a similar style to the input as well